# How to connect SQLite with Java?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, classpath

I am using one simple code to access the SQLite database from Java application .
My code is

```
 import java.sql.Connection;  
 import java.sql.DriverManager;  
 import java.sql.ResultSet;  
 import java.sql.Statement;  
 public class ConnectSQLite 
 {  
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {  
     Connection connection = null;  
     ResultSet resultSet = null;  
     Statement statement = null;  

     try 
     {  
         Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");  
         connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:D:\\testdb.db");  
         statement = connection.createStatement();  
         resultSet = statement  
                 .executeQuery("SELECT EMPNAME FROM EMPLOYEEDETAILS");  
         while (resultSet.next()) 
         {  
             System.out.println("EMPLOYEE NAME:"  
                     + resultSet.getString("EMPNAME"));  
         }  
     } 
     catch (Exception e) 
     {  
         e.printStackTrace();  
     }
     finally 
     {  
         try 
         {  
             resultSet.close();  
             statement.close();  
             connection.close();  
         } 
         catch (Exception e) 
         {  
             e.printStackTrace();  
         }  
     }  
 }  
}
```

But this code gives one exception like

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC
```

How can I slove this,please help me.

Comment: I guess you are not putting SQLite jar in classpath

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You need to have a SQLite JDBC driver in your classpath.

Taro L. Saito (xerial) forked the Zentus project and now maintains it under the name [sqlite-jdbc](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc). It bundles the native drivers for major platforms so you don't need to configure them separately.

Comment: i am using this driver, and works fine. But why it is not compacting database while creating.With FireFox sqlite plugin Database compacted from 11.5MB to 11.3MB. how to do that with java.

Comment: @Dyapa You need to periodically run `VACUUM`; since JDBC doesn't actually interpret the SQL (for _very_ good reasons) just send it over. Or use a pragma per connection to run in auto-vacuum mode.

Comment: @DonalFellows can u explain how to run VACUUM through java.

Comment: For those experiencing this issue with Tomcat this jar needs to be put into the lib folder for respective Tomcat version.  Tomcat will also need to be restarted.  

In the web application, the jar needs to be placed into the WEB-INF lib folder as well.  You don't need to add it to the build path because putting it in the WEB-INF lib folder places it there automatically.

Comment: @AndroidAddict Thank you bro you saved hours of my time :)

Comment: @AndroidAddict thank you so much ıhave been struggling with this issue over an hour... thank you dude thank you :)

Comment: @DyapaSrikanth: Execute a query (or an update, not sure which) with the text `VACUUM`.  Example: `statement.executeQuery("VACUUM");`

Answer (score 9):

If you are using netbeans Download the [sqlitejdbc driver](http://files.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/sqlitejdbc-v056.jar)
Right click the Libraries folder from the Project window and select Add Library ,
then click on the Create button  enter the Library name (SQLite) and hit OK

You have to add the sqlitejdbc driver to the class path , click on the 
Add Jar/Folder.. button and select the sqlitejdbc file you've downloaded previously 
Hit OK and you are ready to go !

Comment: I struggled a lot because of this problem. I am a Java newbie and using Netbeans.
It's been a frustration. Finally, your answer saved my day.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using `Netbeans` using `Maven` to add library is easier. I have tried using above solutions but it didn't work.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
      <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>3.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I have added `Maven` dependency and `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC` error gone.

Answer (score 6):

I'm using Eclipse and I copied your code and got the same error.  I then opened up the project properties->Java Build Path -> Libraries->Add External JARs...
c:\jrun4\lib\sqlitejdbc-v056.jar
Worked like a charm.  You may need to restart your web server if you've just copied the .jar file.

Answer (score 3):

```
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import org.sqlite.SQLiteDataSource;
    import org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader;

    public class Test {

        public static final boolean Connected() {
            boolean initialize = SQLiteJDBCLoader.initialize();

            SQLiteDataSource dataSource = new SQLiteDataSource();
            dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:sqlite:/home/users.sqlite");
            int i=0;
            try {
                ResultSet executeQuery = dataSource.getConnection()
                        .createStatement().executeQuery("select * from \"Table\"");
                while (executeQuery.next()) {
i++;
                    System.out.println("out: "+executeQuery.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(i));

                }



            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
            }

            return initialize;

        }
```

Comment: I was using `dataSource.setDatabaseName(...)` and it wasn't working. Now I see I needed to use `dataSource.setUrl(...)`. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You have to download and add the SQLite JDBC driver to your classpath.
You can download from here https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads

If you use Gradle, you will only have to add the SQLite dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.8.11.2'
}
```

Next thing you have to do is to initialize the driver:

```
try {
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException eString) {
    System.err.println("Could not init JDBC driver - driver not found");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:D:\\testdb.db");
```

Instead of this put

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:D:\\testdb");
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey i have posted a video tutorial on youtube about this, you can check that and you can find here the sample code :

http://myfundatimemachine.blogspot.in/2012/06/database-connection-to-java-application.html

Comment: Its a lot of irrelevant code to learn about a relatively specific problem. Not saying its a bad video/code, but not specific for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;   


public class Connectdatabase {

        Connection con = null;

        public static Connection ConnecrDb(){

            try{
                //String dir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
                Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:D:\\testdb.db");
                return con;
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Problem with connection of database");
                return null;
            }
        }

    }
```