# Is there a driver for SQLite in Java?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, driver

I did some research on their site, and after some Google-ing, it looks like there are only drivers for C & C++. Is there an open driver that I can use with SQLLite, or is there a way I can use it with JDBC?

**UPDATE**

I'm doing development on Linux, but I would like to keep my options open. Native libraries would work, but wouldn't give the cross-platform freedom that I'm used to with Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite is a native library - therefore a platform independent solution is not that simple. The [SQLiteJDBC](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/) project uses a internally complex but working system for accessing SQLite database platform independent (on most platform with a good speed). As the name implies it can be used via JDBC (see code sample on the main page).

If you only need one specific platform you can also use the [SQLite Java wrapper](http://www.ch-werner.de/javasqlite/). For windows there are pre-compiled binaries; sources are also available.

Comment: Know of any native libraries for Linux that will do the same thing?

Comment: Providing pre-compiled binaries for Linux is a big problem. I tried it once - you have to compile everything statically into the lib. Better to directly compile the SQLite Java wrapper (via standard make && make install) or directly use the SQLite Java wrapper. The latter includes a lot of native JNI libraries for different platforms and if none matches it uses some emulation code which should run everywhere.

Comment: The link is broken; here's SQLiteJDBC on github: https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc

Answer (score 4):

[SQLite JDBC](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc) is completely written in Java, so there are no external dependencies.

Comment: I have not heard of that, I will look into it as an option

Answer (score 4):

I have used [org:xerial:sqlite-jdbc](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/)

Example Groovy script:

```
@Grab(group='org.xerial', module='sqlite-jdbc', version='[3.6.4,)')
sql = groovy.sql.Sql.newInstance("jdbc:sqlite:test.db","org.sqlite.JDBC")
sql.execute("create table students(name, age)")
```

(note: 3.6.4 is not the latest version)

Comment: sqlite-jdbc (now at version 2017-10-08: sqlite-jdbc-3.20.1) is hosted at github: https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc      See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1525453/1689714

Answer (score 1):

There is also SQLJet, which is a pure java impl which is compatible with sqlite.