# Access SQLite database from non-android environment

Tags: android, unit-testing, sqlite, drivers

Here is my situation: I have two sets of tests for my android application. One set that uses "normal" non-android libraries (`JUnit4`, `JMock2`, etc.), to unit-test my business logic, and one set that uses the Android framework (`ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` and soon `Robotium`), to test my UI.

I'd like to add integration tests for my `SQLite` database (CRUD tests, etc.) in my  non-android set of tests. Is there a way to do that? Is there a `SQLite` driver that works in a normal environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, check out [SqliteJDBC](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/). More discussion of this here:

[How to connect SQLite with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525444/how-to-connect-sqlite-with-java)

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody stumbles on this question, currently two other SQLite JDBC drivers are more popular: [Xerial](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc) and [SQLDroid](https://github.com/SQLDroid/SQLDroid).