# SQLite Connection String Configuration

Tags: java, database, sqlite, connection

I have a SQLite database file with name localEntry.sqlite on my Desktop of the system. I want to read the data of one of the table of this database. For this I write a code in Eclipse to access all the data form one of the table.:

```
public class SqliteDbRead {

private static String col1;
private static String col2;


public static void main(String[] args) throws 
    SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

    //Get Connection
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:localEntry.sqlite");

    //obtain a statement
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    String query = "select * from submitted_table";

    //Execute Query
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

    while (rs.next()) {

        col1 = rs.getString("col1");
        col2 = rs.getString("col2");


    } //while
    con.close();
} //main
}
```

This code work fine when the localEntry.sqlite file is in my JavaProject. Here I don't know what is connection string (or any other method) if this database file is on Desktop or on other place in computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this question, it has a connection string to the D-Drive of a windows machine: [How to connect SQLite with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525444/how-to-connect-sqlite-with-java)