# SQLite manager, Add on to FireFox

Tags: java, sqlitemanager

I'm new to databases and i need to use it for a project i am working on, i have the following question.

If we use SQLite manager to create a database on java and then produce a jar file of the complete program. To install this project do we have to always have the SQLite Manager add-on for FireFox for every computer this program is going to be installed on. Despite having the ability to add and remove things from the database in my program in a GUI.

Comment: Go through first answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525444/how-to-connect-sqlite-with-java

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not necessary to include extra tools if your program contains every functionality that is needed to operate the database.  In some cases it's even better when the end user can't directly access the database, to avoid all kinds of data corruption issues.

That being said, it can be nice to offer a generic tool alongside your solution, and SQLite Manager would be an excellent choice.  Check out [this list of SQLite management tools](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ManagementTools) for other possible choices.

As a sidenote, there are embeddable database engines that are written in Java and may be easier/more natural to integrate in a Java program than SQLIte - examples of this type of product are [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/) and [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html)