# sqlite in java not outputting

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I'm super new to sqlite and java. I'm on a mac, I know that can make a difference sometime. I'm trying to create a database in sqlite, create a table, add some values, do a query for values in the table, print them out.  I'm not sure if any of that's happening though. I can't get the system to successfully `System.out.println();` after this line of code `Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");` until I get to `catch(Exception e)`.

I've had a lot of trouble trying to get this to connect. I know mac OS X has sqlite packaged with it. This entire process was much easier with mySQL. Anytips would be greatly appreciated.

The output in terminal is `org.sqlite.JDBC` but that's all I get. Anyway here's my code, and thanks for your help.

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class litef3
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    try
    {
//call sqlite class
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
//create connection instantiation and create db called mydata.db(sqlite)
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:mydata.db");
//create statement instantiation (sqlite)
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();         
//create a table called mytable in mydata.db(sqlite statment)
        stmt.executeUpdate("create table mytable(name char(20), age int)");
//insert values into mytable
        stmt.executeUpdate("insert into mytable values('name 1', 1)");
        stmt.executeUpdate("insert into mytable values('name 2', 2)");
        stmt.executeUpdate("insert into mytable values('name 3', 3)");
//read from the database (sqlite)
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from mytable");
        while(rs.next())
        {
// read the result set
            System.out.println("name = " + rs.getString("name"));
            System.out.println("age = " + rs.getInt("age"));
        }
        stmt.close();
        con.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a duplicate of [How to connect SQLite with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525444/how-to-connect-sqlite-with-java?rq=1)

Your code is throwing a ClassNotFoundException, so please follow the above link to fix that. As it need the SQLLite JDBC driver to work.

Comment: This ^. You didn't add the SQLite library to your project.

Comment: the link to follow in the link you suggested does not load.  I have tried just going to www.zentus.com as well. I have used three different web browsers to verify this. If I download the xerial SQLite library and place it in the same fold that I placed the mySQL library I get a ton of "exception in main thread" errors.

Comment: Do you guys have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with this I found a solution to the problem. www.zentus.com is down and has been every time I have tried to connect to it over the last few days.  I tried the https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads, the 3.8.4 jdbc gave me problems, I tried the 3.7.2 jdbc and it worked like a charm

so to sum it all up, if you are trying to connect to sqlite on a mac using java and you already have  sqlite access through terminal, you need to download the 3.7.2 jdbc from https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads and place the .jar in the java extensions folder. the full file path is `/System/Library/Java/Extensions/` and the file you place there was labelled sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar when I downloaded it on 3.15.14.  Good luck to everyone who might be struggling with this