# Insert in a sqlite database from jsp

Tags: java, linux, database, sqlite, jsp

I have a JSP in linux machine and a sqlite database

```
<%!
"/usr/bin/sqlite3 -echo /home/sqlitedb.db 'insert into transactions values (\""+number+"\",\""+time+"\",\""+check+"\",\""+package+"\",\""+type+"\");'"

%>
```

And i have a sqlite database in my linux `sqlitedb.db`

Then how can i insert the values from my JSP to the sqlite database, i thing with a `runtime.exec(command`);

But i do not know how.

Who can help me?

Comment: i guess this may help [How to insert data into SQL lite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525444/how-to-connect-sqlite-with-java)

Comment: Using the runtime for this is a bad idea, do it programtically with a sqlite driver, however if you **need** to use runtime, it's `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("command")`