# How to replace a line in a text file using Java?

Tags: java, text, replace

I have a text file with various key value pairs separated with a '--'.
Below is the code I have so far

```
        File file = new File("C:\\StateTestFile.txt");
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(file.getAbsolutePath());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
           if(line.contains("content_style")) {
               //Write to the line currently reading and save back to the file
           }
        }
        br.close();

        out.close();
```

What I would like to do is read this text file and replace the value of a specific line with something I specify. So id want to find the 'content_style' line and replace 'posh' with 'dirty'.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you ask a more specific question? We're not here to do your assignments for you. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Comment: see the methods `replace` and `replaceAll` of `String`. The latter can also use regular expressions

Comment: You can do this exactly as you described: read the file, change the string, write to file. If you need more detailed answers, you need to show some effort, such as what you attempted so far.

Comment: other helpful methods I could see being used here would be `String.split` and `String.contains`

Comment: @Grice

I've added the code i currently have. Hopefully its more clear.

Comment: System.out.println(line.replace("posh", "dirty"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in-place on a single file only if you are sure that the string you are replacing is *exactly the same length in bytes* as the string that replaces it. Otherwise, you can't add or delete characters in a single file, but you can create a new file.

1. Open the source file for reading.
2. Open the destination file for writing.
3. Read each line in the source file, use `replaceAll`, and write it to the destination file.
4. Close both files.

Alternate method that preserves the key-value semantics:

1. Open the source file for reading.
2. Open the destination file for writing.
3. Split each line in the source file into a key and value pair. If the key equals `"content_style"`, write the key and `"dirty"` to the destination file. Otherwise write the key and value.
4. Close both files.

Finally, delete the old file and rename the new file on top of the old one. If you're going to be doing key-value manipulations often, and you don't want to write out a new file all the time, it might be worth it to use a database. Look for a [JDBC driver for SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525444/how-to-connect-sqlite-with-java).

Comment: Thanks this seems to be the approach I need. I thought it would be easy to just read and write back to the same file but the line is not actually being saved back to the file.

Answer (score 1):

simply use:

```
 line = line.replaceAll("posh", "dirty"); // as strings are immutable in java
```

Comment: This also works. In error, I had tried passing it directly to the line , which would have overwritten the replaced text.