# Java - SQLite connection (No suitable driver found for JDBC:sqlite:main.db)

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I have problem with SQLite connection on my Java project. Error looks like this :

> No suitable driver found for JDBC:sqlite:main.db

That's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {

    Connection c = null;
    try {
      //  Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        String url = "JDBC:sqlite:main.db";
        c = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        System.out.println("Connection to sql");
    } catch ( SQLException e ) {
        System.err.println( e.getMessage() );
    } finally {
        try{
            if( c!= null ) {
                c.close();
            }
        }catch( SQLException ex )
        {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Can You help me please?

Answer (score 6):

If you're using maven, ensure that the `scope` isn't specified as test.i.e.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.18.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

"No suitable driver" means that the connection URL is incorrect for the JDBC driver JAR that was loaded.

Case matters: it should be `jdbc:sqlite:main.db`.  Please read the [tutorial](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not added the SQLITE JDBC driver to your classpath. Just download the jar [FROM HERE](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/sqlite/sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar.zip) and add it to your classpath. Your error would be resolved.

You should also have a look on [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525444/how-to-connect-sqlite-with-java?rq=1) and [This resource](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/sqlite-jdbc-driver/).
By reading both of them you will learn more about SQLITE as well as how to make a connection with JDBC.

Comment: Please include the relevant parts in your answer, don't only rely on links only. On top of that, it doesn't even address the actual problem: the wrong case of `"JDBC:..."` instead of `"jdbc:..."`.

Comment: @Mark honestly I didn't knew the actual answer. Hence I gave the working examples links so that the questioner will benefit from some extra details given on those links, and that might give an extra edge to his knowledge and expertise. Thanks for pointing out, I will take care from the next time.

Comment: In that case it is better to leave a comment, instead of answering.

Comment: yeah sure, I was not fully aware of these stackoverflow rules. Thanks,