# Java sqlite3 table to class members/Objects

Tags: java, sqlite

I would like to map my class members to sqlite3 table.
For eg:

```
public class MyConfigs{
String IpUno;
int Port;
int OnTx;
double xyz;
...........//May have 100 members of different datatypes
}
```

My table will be having 3 columns Id Integer,Parameter (VarChar),Value(VarChar).How can I read and update the values using object mapping or some other method so that my code is reusable? I am trying to make this application in linux ubuntu and my target sysytem is having debian jessie and the IDE is netbeans.I appreciate your support.
[My Db Table may look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRAF5.jpg)

Comment: See [How to connect to SQLite with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525444/how-to-connect-sqlite-with-java).  Also, look into using Hibernate with the SQLite JDBC JAR.

Comment: Thanks Tim ,connecting sqlite using jdbc driver is done but i need to map my rows to my class objects